# Clean code , testing and re-usability clarification

Tags: testing, reusability, code-cleanup

Aiming for `clean code` and `testing` . Each *function / method* , should do **one and only one** thing. this is the theory. to illustrate that i want to share with you some code and then  question.

Let's say we need a method that will return a list of players if a condition is true and an empty list of the condition is false.

### First approach: One method:

```
public List<int> ListOfPlayersIDs(int InputNumber)
             {
                 if (Condition)
                 {
                     return new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3}); // return a list with items
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     return new List<int>();//return an empty list
                 }

             }
```

So here the method ListOfPlayersIDs performs two things:

1. returns a list of players
2. Verify if a condition is valid and returns an empty list if not

To divide those "functionality" we can have one method to check the condition and one to return the list of players.

Something like this:

---

### Second approach: Two methods:

### First Method

```
public bool ArePlayerValidForThisNumber(int InputNumber)
{
If (condition)
return true;
else return false;
//Or simply return condition;
}
```

---

### Second method

```
public List<int> ListOfPlayersIDs(int InputNumber)
             {
          return new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3}); // return a list with items 
}
```

## My question is :

Which approach do you follow and apply in your coding.
For me the second one is testable, reusable and each method does exactly what it suppose to do. but isn't just a theory in books? I read a lot of code and it does not respect this pattern.

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 3):

It depends (tm). And it depends if you make your code cleaner and easier to understand when you break things into smaller methods.

Personally I would keep the external interface the same (the method can return a filled list or empty), as otherwise, if your client needs to do code if/else clause, you might be leaking logic. Also, I would use an approach called 'code at two levels of abstraction' or 'each method should descend one level of abstraction'. By doing this the final code might look like

```
public List<int> ListOfPlayersIDs(int InputNumber)
{
   if (methodDescribingTheBusinessCondition()) {
      return methodDescribingPositiveOutcome(); 
   } else {
      return methodNameDescribingNegativeOutcome();
   }
}
```

The idea is that all of this should read like "normal" English, so someone reading the code will get the idea of what's going on without having to know all the nitty gritty details. Here each method is also doing just one thing and the method that orchestrates the whole thing is usually called a "policy" (as it describes your functionality).

If your method is simple, this level of abstraction might make it more difficult to understand.

Last but not least, this approach is explained in a few books (Clean Code to be very specific), and it's used as a good practice in professional development.

Comment: Clean Code (the book) is my ultimate reference and i would love if all programmers respect the approaches and methodologies there.

Read like "normal" english , i think is the key for anyone else to read your code and not spending years trying to decipher it.

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker There's another great book titles *Growing Object-Oriented Software: Guided by tests*, which is also filled with good practices. I hope I answered your question, as this approach is definitely used in by many developers.